# Where do I get or find the PublicKeyToken for the latest version of Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I am upgrading from EF 6.0 to EF 6.1. The actual EF dll version is 6.1.30225.0. When I upgrade via NuGet, this is the dll version I see. After the upgrade, I am still seeing references in project files to EntityFrameworkSection Version=6.0.0.0 in my config files (app.config, web.config, etc).

Do I need to update these references as well? If so, what version for 6.1.30225.0? 6.1.3.0 or just 6.1.0.0? Do I need a new PublicKeyToken?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are still 6.0.0.0 So, you dont have to update them. :)
Good luck!